# Yii2 Breadcrumbs with microdata

Tags: yii2, schema.org, breadcrumbs, microdata

How to add microdata (schema.org) to Yii2 Breadcrumps?

I have the following code in the application layout:

```
<?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
    'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ?? []
]); ?>
```

I want to add microdata attributes for breadcrumbs (https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add attribute values to `options`, `itemTemplate` and `activeItemTemplate`:

```
<?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
    'links' => $this->params['breadcrumbs'] ?? [],
    'options' => ['class' => 'breadcrumb', 'itemscope' => true, 'itemtype' => 'http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList'],
    'itemTemplate' => '<li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">{link}</li>' . PHP_EOL,
    'activeItemTemplate' => '<li class="active" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">{link}</li>' . PHP_EOL,
]); ?>
```

UPDATE:

In fact, for Google it does not work as expected: `itemprop="position"` and `itemprop="item"` required inside `<li></li>`. See https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb